# Zend 2 Auth with Bcrypt?

Tags: zend-framework2, bcrypt, zend-auth

Google doesn't have much of a solution ([similar question but no answer](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Authentication-amp-DbTable-Adapter-with-Bcrypt-td4657400.html)).

Because bcrypt generates a new hash each time, the authentication fails. I've looked into the code (perhaps extend class myself) but it's pretty messy (would prefer a native solution). How can I use the `$bcrpt->verify()` with `$identity->isValid()`?

Edit: For now, I've subclassed the authentication DbTable class, and it's working, but I highly doubt it's optimized/"fully right". Still looking for an "elegant" solution.

Comment: It's indeed a pitty that ZF2 has a Bcrypt wrapper but doesn't provide a Brypt auth adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you should know, BCrypt hashes using a salt. And that salt is generated again randomly each time. That drastically increases the hardness of finding all passwords if your database is compromised. Thus, indeed, it will generate a new hash each time.

My own solution for the problem that you were having, is having my own `Zend\Authentication` adapter, that would retrieve a user model from the database (using the username/email), and then calling `$user->checkPassword($credential);`. That method would get an instance of `Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt`. Which would simply call `$bcrypt->verify()` on the given password, and the hash in the user model.

Comment: i have also a similar problem , 
@kokx how we can make this? 
please can you  give  a example.

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CallbackCheckAdapter
```

Like this :

```
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CallbackCheckAdapter as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt;    

$credentialValidationCallback = function($dbCredential, $requestCredential) {
    return (new Bcrypt())->verify($requestCredential, $dbCredential);
};
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'user', 'login', 'password', $credentialValidationCallback);
// ...
```

Comment: Great solution and very tidy. Thanks!

Comment: It should be standard!

Comment: Works like a charm! Only the callback needed. 
This is the best solution I think since you have nothing more to change prior to the call is isValid method

Comment: This is definitely the way to go when using ZF auth service. Of course, there is not a single right way but that one should be referred as the standart ZF way.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this (test code and it works)..;

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
                $user   = new User();
                $user->exchangeArray($form->getData());

                $password    = $user->password;
                $data        = $this->getUserTable()->selectUser($user->username);

                if (!$data)
                {
                    echo 'user not found';
                } else {

                    if ($bcrypt->verify($password, $data->hash)) {

                    $sm          = $this->getServiceLocator();
                    $dbAdapter   = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter(
                                            $dbAdapter,
                                            'cms_users',
                                            'username',
                                            'hash'
                                        );
                    $authAdapter->setIdentity($user->username)
                                ->setCredential($data->hash);                           

                    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
                    echo $result->getIdentity() . "\n\n";
                    // do you thing on succes/failure


                    } else {
                    echo 'invalid password';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: First of all you are doing an extra DB call, check the user entered password with the hash from the first DB call, then use the hash from the first DB call to authenticate with hash which is in DB using 2nd DB call.
This will work but it is not the right way. I think the solution that @bigBen provided is the correct way.